# SSRS Grouping in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, dropdown, ssrs-grouping

I need help in generating a tablix using same dataset but should be displayed separately based on dropdown input selection( multi values). Currently i am working on Tablix please let me know if i can use anything else to achieve the output.

Here is my example where i have dropdown with multiple input selection and when i select two students i am getting results into one table instead i want to separate into two tables based on studentID.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpStudent( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name varchar(150))

INSERT INTO #tmpStudent(Name)
VALUES('John') ,
('Mike'), 
('Albert')

CREATE TABLE #tmpDepartment (ID INT
IDENTITY(1,1), StudentID INT, DepartmentName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #tmpDepartment ( StudentID, DepartmentName)
VALUES(1, 'Computers'), 
(2, 'Computers'), 
(1, 'Science'), 
(3, 'Mechanical')

DECLARE @xStudent VARCHAR(30) ='John,Mike'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT s.ID, s.Name, d.DepartmentName
            FROM #tmpStudent s 
            INNER JOIN #tmpDepartment d 
             ON s.ID = d.StudentID
            WHERE s.Name IN('''+ Replace(@xStudent, ',', ''',''') + ''')
            ORDER BY s.ID'
--PRINT @Sql 
exec sp_executesql @Sql

DROP TABLE #tmpStudent, #tmpDepartment
```

Current Output

```
ID  Name    DepartmentName
1   John    Computers
1   John    Science
2   Mike    Computers
```

Below is the excepted output where i have to repeat the same tablix based on StudentID(based on multiple input selection in dropdownlist)

```
ID  Name    DepartmentName
1   John    Computers
1   John    Science

ID  Name    DepartmentName
2   Mike    Computers
```

Comment: This kind of question has been answered many time. As a start point, look at the `Sub report` option very breifly described in my answer to another questio here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212190/ssrs-create-as-many-tables-as-needed-using-one-dataset-based-on-a-dataset-fiel/53212832#53212832 or an alternative way where https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122785/ssrs-report-with-groups-and-page-breaks/50123637#50123637

If you need more details search about sub reports and loops and there are plenty of examples. They are easy to do even if they don;t sound it at first.

Comment: Use the LIST object (which is just another table) to group by Student ID and then put your current table inside of it. Similar to a subreport but without as much work.